# How to connect a Postgres Docker image from another Docker container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, connection-string

I am trying to set up [this Bullet Train API server](https://github.com/BulletTrainHQ/bullet-train-api) on our machines. I am successfully able to run their Python server using the `docker-compose up` method.

As per the docs, it needs the database as well. I preferred using the docker image for the Postgres DB `docker run --name local_postgres -d -P postgres` which returns this:

[image: fb8b349961ff064e652d4f76402acd900c2fe4764475e3f487e84afd7407f70c]

It doesn't return a success message saying if the Postgres Docker is running successfully or not. It just returns some kinda long string which I feel should be an identifier of the Postgres Docker image.

As I need to connect [this Bullet Train API server](https://github.com/BulletTrainHQ/bullet-train-api) to this Dockerized database -

The question is how to find the connection string for this Postgres Docker image?

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use docker-compose. Put your application image in there as one service and your postgres image as a second service. Then also include an overlay network in the stack and specify that in each of your services. After that it is possible for the application to access the database via the docker service's name "local_postgres" as the hostname.

**Update as per your comment**

Make sure that your dockerfile that defines the postgres container contains an EXPOSE command.

```
EXPOSE 5432
```

If missing, add it and rebuild the container.

Start the container and include the below option, which will expose the database port on localhost.

```
docker run --name local_postgres -p 5432:5432 -d -P postgres
```

Check if the port is really exposed by typing

```
docker ps | grep 'local_postgres'
```

You should see something like this in the output.

> PORTS 0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp

If you see this output, the port 5432 is successfully exposed on your host. So if your app runs on localhost, you can access the database via localhost:5432

Comment: I'm looking for a way to connect to the Postgres running inside a Docker from a terminal. Not necessary from another Docker network